# Issue with scheduling a bash script with crontab

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, cron

Using:

```
20 21 * * *  /bin/sh /Users/username/Documents/first.sh
```

to execute my script which does btw have this at the top:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and instead I am getting this:

```
You have new mail in /var/mail/username
```

with the following output:

```
/Users/username/Documents/first.sh: line 3: wget: command not found
/Users/username/Documents/first.sh: line 4: wget: command not found
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I get an email every time my cron scripts run.  The email contains all the output.

Comment: @EdHeal fixed it based on what the message in my mail stated. Can you explain why the "error" if you will gets recorded there?

Comment: Here's an explanation of the chrontab email system: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html (search for email)

Comment: Crontab runs in the background. You are out of the room when it is executed

Comment: Either put wget into the PATH. I.e. Get the script to update the PATH environment variable or put the full path infront of the command

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: /bin/sh can be different shells, so run `ls -l /bin/sh` so see which one you are using.  Also, try `which wget` to make sure that command is available.  If wget is available for you, it might not be available to the user configured for crontab, or it might not be in the path of the current environment.  You can try changing wget to the full path to wget, e.g. /usr/bin/wget

Comment: Perhaps you could install `wget` using `brew`: http://brew.sh/

Comment: @AlexWoolford I do have wget installed, it works perfectly in my script. :-) Anyways, solved the problem, see below.

Comment: @Tony yep, it is the correct sh

Answer (score 2):

Even though you made your cron job work somehow, I'd really like to point out that your "solution" seems irrelevant.

1. "bash first.sh" is not a good idea since the beginning of the script starts with "#!/bin/sh", which means: you simply "first.sh" and the system will interpret it using "/bin/sh".
2. "cd /Users/username/Documents" does NOT solve the "command not found" issue.

This is actually a common issue with cron jobs. The root cause is: the cron jobs (first.sh in this case) run in a "clean" environment. That is, your profile is not sourced. Consequently, the PATH env var contains only a minimal number of path and unfortunately the "wget" is not in those paths.

Solution: it is simple and straight forward. You can

1. evoke wget etc. with their absolute paths. Or
2. setup PATH accordingly (or source in corresponding profiles) at the beginning of you script.

For the sake of security, we usually prefer to call external commands (wget etc.) using absolute paths.

Answer (score -2):

Thank-you everyone, I have found a solution:

I modified my crontab file:

34 21 * * * cd /Users/username/Documents && bash first.sh

Comment: so the path is in the local .bashrc